# When I mount my USB drive, all Chinese characters of names of files/directories are displayed as question marks

Tags: mount, usb-drive, filename, chinese

When I create or rename a file with Chinese characters(like `我的源程序.c`) on Windows, and reboot it to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /mnt`, and use `ls /mnt` command, it shows `?????.c`.
I used `sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /mnt -o iocharset=utf8`, but it did not work.
The Chinese filenames are fine in the partitions of local disks.
The system language is currently Simplified Chinese.

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed the proper language packs for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Try `sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /mnt -o utf8`

Comment: @pasmanpasmański It still does not work…

Comment: System settings > Region & Language -> Add Simplified Chinese

Comment: @pasmanpasmański But it is currently “Simplified Chinese”…

Comment: Try adding codepage to the mount parameters. For example: iocharset=utf8,codepage=(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0918/localization-12/index.html)

Comment: It is still like that.